# How to go from .prj file information to the appropriate d3 projection code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning D3.js and one thing I struggle with is projection.

I am currently working on a map of New Zealand with the following .prj information:

```
ROJCS["NZGD2000_New_Zealand_Transverse_Mercator_2000",
GEOGCS["GCS_NZGD_2000",DATUM["D_NZGD_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

How can I use this information (I assumed that the information I need is there) to write my projection code in D3.js?

Except the fact that I should use the transverseMercator() method, everything else is still confusing to me.

With that minimal code:

```
var projection = d3.geo.transverseMercator()
.scale(50);
```

I only display an inconsistent mix of lines for the moment.

Comment: I would convert to geojson with a projection that you control so that you can then use that in D3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LarsKotthoff. Is that the preferred way of doing it? I have the shp and prj files and struggle with the projection. My current assumption is that most of the time, you just adjust the projection by try and see and by filling in magic numbers. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to adjust mine properly for the moment: the map seems well centered and the size ok (I guess that scale and translate are ok) but instead of a map I see an artistic mix of lines. That means that rotate is what I have wrong, right? Any systematic approach to get it correct? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your data may be incorrect. I don't know what you mean by "preferred" and "systematic", but I would certainly convert with a known projection that I can then work with instead of trying to shoehorn things into place afterwards.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff would you have a recommendation on a specific projection to select?

Comment: If I remember correctly, EPSG:4326 is the one that works best.

Comment: Ok, thanks @LarsKotthoff!